# Tableau Saving Custom View : uncaught security error: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a custom page where it will load my tableau report using tableau JS API.

Assuming my custom webpage is : [www.test1.com](http://www.test1.com)

TableauServer where my report resides is : [www.devtableau.com](http://www.devtableau.com)

On my custom webpage. all functionality is working as expected. the only error im receiving is when i am trying to save a custom view . When i tried creating a custom view on my custom webpage . Error is prompting :

```
Unexpected Error
An unexpected error occurred. If you continue to receive this error please contact your Tableau Server Administrator.
Session ID: BAF6E841BA4B405BBA08EE849582CBE5-2:0
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.devtableau.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

based on the document found -> https://kb.tableau.com/articles/Issue/error-uncaught-securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-when-saving-a-custom-view-in-an-embedded-view-occurred-on-tableau-server

It is saying that this is a known error on tableau on version 2019,
im on the latest tableau version .
Is there a workaround on this ? Or a configuration that needed to be set on tableauserver such as allowing [www.test1.com](http://www.test1.com) ?